# OS X cannot detach volume, hdiutil error

Tags: java, macos, installation, osx-elcapitan, unmount

I need to install Java from command line. This is what I am trying:

```
hdiutil attach javaforosx.dmg
cd /Volumes/Java\ for\ OS\ X\ 2015-001/
sudo installer -pkg JavaForOSX.pkg -target "/"
sudo hdiutil detach hdiutil detach /Volumes/Java\ for\ OS\ X\ 2015-001/
```

It fails at the last step, with the error message:

```
hdiutil: couldn't unmount "disk2" - Resource busy
```

What more, if I now go to my desktop and manually try to eject the disk image that is showing up in regards to Java (right click -> Eject) it says I cannot eject it, the terminal is using it. I have to close the terminal and only then I am able to eject the disk.

How do I do it correctly from command line?

Comment: Have you tried to exit from the image directory (out of `/Volumes/Java\ for\ OS\ X\ 2015-001/`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to exit the image directory too. Probably if you change the `cd` to a `pushd` and then before doing a `hdiutil detach` just do a `popd`.
This will get back to your working directory. So just change your script to something like:

```
hdiutil attach javaforosx.dmg
pushd /Volumes/Java\ for\ OS\ X\ 2015-001/
sudo installer -pkg JavaForOSX.pkg -target "/"
popd
sudo hdiutil detach /Volumes/Java\ for\ OS\ X\ 2015-001/
```

Also, note that if you have [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) installed, you can use [cask](http://caskroom.io/) to install `java` from command line too. Like:

```
brew cask install java7
```

This will also take care of the download details and

Comment: Ah right. `cd`-ing out of the directory solved the issue. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, it is not entirely silent, the intermediate window with the pkg file still shows up during installation. It does go away when the installation is complete, but it still shows up during installation, and if the command line is in full screen mode, the screen shifts to the desktop while doing that. Is it possible to escape that as well, and do it really silently?

Comment: @Cupidvogel Did you identify the step that triggers the window? Is it the `dmg` finder image browser or the `installer` setup window?

Comment: You can add `-nobrowse` argument, that will not show the image in the finder anymore.

Comment: That's awesome! Works like a charm!